# PHP Laravel: Validator to check input for int

Tags: php, laravel, validation

Using PHP Laravel's Validator, how do I check the input for int?

I've tried using is_int but its the wrong direction.

```
    class ProductsController extends Controller
    {
        public function listproduct(){

  return view('products.listproduct');

}

public function saveproduct(Request $request){

  $this->validate($request, [
      ...
      'payment' => 'required|is_int()',  
      ...
  ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [closure validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#using-closures) or create custom:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    ...
    'payment' => function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
        if (!is_int($value)) {
            return $fail($attribute . ' should be integer.');
        }
    }
    ...
]);
```

Keep in mind that custom rules will not work correctly with min and max rules.

Answer (score 0):

this package add more parameter for type checking:

https://github.com/qtlenh/laravel-strict-validator

just change rules to:

```
'payment' => 'required|integer:strict'
```

or cast input to type integer

```
'payment' => 'required|integer:cast'
```

Comment: Please [read](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) before you post any more answers here.

Answer (score -2):

Simply read the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-integer) to find the rules you need

```
$this->validate($request, [
  ...
  'payment' => 'required|integer',  
  ...
]);
```

Comment: this is not the same as is_int! For example "4" passes the laravel integer check, but is_int("4") is false, I need a validation which really checks if the input is a int so that type checks of my methods work

Comment: inputs from html are all text. there is no integer in http request

Comment: yes but json is text. once you convert json to an object of different types then its nolonger in request and you just use plain is_int

Comment: maybe this is only Lumen-specific, but I use Lumen and there I can have requests where the input is already a json object and I can use normal input validation to validate this object, when I now use integer as validation it doesn't validate its type, so I have to validate again, which is in my opinion not the idea of input validation if I want to allow an input {id: 1} and do not allow an input {id: "1"} this is a difference for me ...

Comment: that is lumen specific